# Compiling (La)TeX files automatically with GitLab CI with images

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, latex

I am currently attempting to build PDF files automatically with GitLab CI. Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459484/compiling-latex-files-automatically-with-gitlab-ci) I got the basic thing running, however, pdflatex is not able to find my included figures/images:

```
! Unable to load picture or PDF file 'graphics/.../image.png'.
<to be read again> 

Latexmk: Missing input file: 'graphics/.../image.png' from line
'LaTeX Warning: File `graphics/.../image.png' not found on input line 802.'
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - compile

compile_pdf:
  stage: compile
  image: tianon/latex
  script:
    - latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make thing.tex
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - thing.pdf
```

and my makefile looks like this:

```
# From DevSolar https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40759/201491

# You want latexmk to *always* run, because make does not have all the info.
# Also, include non-file targets in .PHONY so they are run regardless of any
# file of the given name existing.
.PHONY: thing.pdf all clean

# The first rule in a Makefile is the one executed by default ("make"). It
# should always be the "all" rule, so that "make" and "make all" are identical.
all: thing.pdf

# CUSTOM BUILD RULES

# In case you didn't know, '$@' is a variable holding the name of the target,
# and '$<' is a variable holding the (first) dependency of a rule.
# "raw2tex" and "dat2tex" are just placeholders for whatever custom steps
# you might have.

# %.tex: %.dat
#         ./dat2tex $< > $@

# MAIN LATEXMK RULE

# -pdf tells latexmk to generate PDF directly (instead of DVI).
# -pdflatex="" tells latexmk to call a specific backend with specific options.
# -use-make tells latexmk to call make for generating missing files.

# -interaction=nonstopmode keeps the pdflatex backend from stopping at a
# missing file reference and interactively asking you for an alternative.

thing.pdf: thing.tex
    latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode" -use-make --shell-escape thing.tex

clean:
    latexmk -CA
```

Both based on [this repo](https://gitlab.com/jasonrwang/dissertation-tudelft-latex). How do I add the images and figures correctly? In all tutorials I found, that use Figures (like [this](https://gitlab.com/sftom/Awesome-CV)), it just worked. Or I am missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the `ctornau/latex` Docker Image to work out of the box.

I have a little template Repo set up at https://gitlab.com/WaldemarLehner/latex-starter

The built PDF can be found at https://waldemarlehner.gitlab.io/latex-starter

And here's my gitlab.ci.yml:

```yaml
build:
  image: ctornau/latex
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - main.pdf
  script:
    # This is needed for colored code blocks. If you dont need
    # them, you can remove this section
    - apt-get -y update
    - apt-get -y install python3-pip
    - pip3 install pygments
    # section end
    - latexmk -shell-escape -pdf main.tex

# This will host the PDF w/ Gitlab Pages
pages:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
  script:
    # Feel free to change the mv target to something else. You will need to update the index.html though
    # Everything inside public will be hosted by Pages
    - mv main.pdf public/main.pdf

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, now it works! However, there is a typo in the image apparently its: ctornau/latex

Comment: you are right! My bad. Fixed it in the my answer